# Shell job-control: possible to "rename" a running job?

Tags: bash, shell, job-control

In the shell (I'm using Bash), I frequently use Ctrl-Z and `fg` to suspend one job and foreground another. An example would be suspending a running instance of Vim and foregrounding a previously suspended REPL. I started Vim with an alias that resolves to `/usr/local/bin/vim`, and the output of `jobs` looks like:

```
$ jobs
[1]+  Stopped       /usr/local/bin/vim print1.hs
[2]   Stopped       stack ghci
```

I could use `fg 2` to specify the `stack ghci` job-spec, but I prefer using tab-completion:

```
fg s<Tab>
```

Similarly, to tab-complete the Vim job-spec, I could `fg /<Tab>`, but it would feel more intuitive to do:

```
fg v<Tab>
```

I have a vague recollection of reading about "renaming" job-specs. Is such a thing possible?

Comment: You may want to consider using a more advanced shell like `zsh` which does that out of the box.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Good to know. I've been intending to try zsh for a while now. Maybe it's time to finally get around to it.